# Tensorflow 1.15 tensor slice: view or new?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

In Tensorflow 1.15, does slicing `Tensor` object with `__getitem__` produce a view for specified part of tensor or new tensor object?

Comment: In TensorFlow, tensors are immutable, so every operation always produces new tensors. Whether memory is copied between tensors or it is reused is an implementation detail that does not change that fact. Simple slices probably reuse the same memory, but for example the documentation of [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) explicitly says that TensorFlow does not support strides, so transposing is an expensive operation (and maybe strided slices?).

Comment: @jdehesa, thanks a lot, after reading your post I realised I should have asked about memory instead.